# Matching Square Brackets with a Regular Expression in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I couldn't find anything that specifically addressed how to find square brackets in predicates on Stack Overflow or on Google so I thought I would post it here and see if anyone can explain the solution.

```
NSString *mstr = @"fasd[981db7007771ffa3]dfaads";
NSString *test =@".*\\[[0-9,a-f]{16}\\].*";
//NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '.*\\\\[[0-9,a-f]{16}\\\\].*'"]; //works
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", test];
if ([pred evaluateWithObject:mstr]) {
    NSLog(@"Yes");
}
```

It seems that when escaping the brackets in-line you need four backslashes but if you put it in a string you only need two.  Not clear why that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because `NSPredicate` does it's own backslash escaping, along with the C-compiler's. So, let's walk through the steps that are done first:

**Source**:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"\\\\[(regex here)\\\\]"];
```

**C-precompiler**: (unescapes one set of backslashes)

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"\\[(regex here)\\]"];
```

**NSPredicate internal compiler**: (unescapes the second set of backlashes, and compiles the regex).

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"\[(regex here)\]"];
```

When passing in a string literal, it is compiled by `NSPredicate` first, whereas when passing a variable, it isn't compiled in the same way (it skips the escaping part).

Comment: That makes sense and matches what I see when I make changes to the regex in the code.